# Should I put a row number filter in join condition or in a prior CTE?

Tags: sql, etl, query-performance, impala

I have a `subscription` table and a `payments` table that I need to join. 
I am trying to decide between 2 options and performance is a key consideration.

Which of the two OPTIONS below will perform better?

I am using Impala, and these tables are large (multiple millions of rows) I am needing to only get one row for every `id` and `date` grouping (hence the `row_number()` analytic function).

I have shortened the queries to illustrate my question:

OPTION 1:

```
WITH cte
   AS (
   SELECT *
      , SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id, date) 
        AS sameday_total
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, date ORDER BY purchase_number DESC)
        AS sameday_rownum
   FROM payments
), 
payment
AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte
    WHERE sameday_rownum = 1
    )
    SELECT s.* 
       , p.sameday_total
    FROM subscription
    INNER JOIN payment ON s.id = p.id
```

---

OPTION 2:

```
WITH payment
   AS (
   SELECT *
          , SUM(payment_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id, date) 
            AS sameday_total
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, date ORDER BY purchase_number DESC)
            AS sameday_rownum
   FROM payments
)
SELECT s.*
       , p.sameday_total
FROM subscription
INNER JOIN payment ON s.id = p.id
                  AND p.sameday_rownum = 1
```

Comment: Just put the condition in the `on` clause.  No need to clutter the query with two CTEs.

Comment: Thank you. So no performance impact either way, given that it's an inner join? I wondered if this is similar to the performance of join condition filtering vs. where clause filtering in final SQL statement's sql predicate?

Comment: You should be able to tell by looking at the query plan to see if the optimizer is going to apply the filter at the beginning or the end.

Comment: Thank you. @Connor, your comment prompted me to look up and read about assessing Impala query performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "**Option 0**" also exists. A far more traditional "derived table" which simply does not require use of any CTE.

```
SELECT s.*
       , p.sameday_total
FROM subscription
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT *
             , SUM(payment_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id, date) 
                 AS sameday_total
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, date ORDER BY purchase_number DESC)
                AS sameday_rownum
           FROM payments
           ) p ON s.id = p.id
                  AND p.sameday_rownum = 1
```

All options 0,1 and 2 are likely to produce identical or very similar explain plans (although I'm more confident about that statement for SQL Server than Impala).

Adopting a CTE does - in itself - not make a query more efficient or better performing, so the syntax alteration between option 1 and 2 isn't major. I prefer option 0 myself as I prefer to use CTEs for specific tasks (e.g. recursion).

What you should do is [use explain plans](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_explain_plan.html) to study what each option produces.